# porque dice que el code no esta definido si es una variable que tomo desde la base de datos?

Tags: codeigniter, mvc, session

estoy tratando de acceder a mi pc con la direccion ip, y me deja normalmente, pero yo instale una maquina virual en mi pc y cuando pongo la ip de la maquina virtual me salen este error, salen 3 errores mas pero todos son similares a este, ponen problema en la variable code que utilizo en la session, trabajo con mvc de codeigniter:

yo tomo la variable code de la base de datos con un metodo getcode():

codigo del controlador:

```
 $code = $this->auth_model->getCode($email);
```

codigo de el modelo:

```
  public function getCode($email){
  $this->db->select('roster_position as code');
  $this->db->where('roster_email',$email);
  $data = $this->db->get('ol_roster');
  $response = $data->row();
  $string = substr($response->code,0);

  return $string;
  }
```

esta es la linea 8 que es la del error

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['code'] == "workforce" || $_SESSION['code']=="real time analyst") { ?>
```

este es el error que me sale:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: code

Filename: layouts/navbar-sidebar.php

Line Number: 8

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\application\views\layouts\navbar-sidebar.php
Line: 8
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\application\controllers\Admin.php
Line: 80
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\olPrueba2\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

alguien me dijo que podia arreglarlo utilizando MY_Controller y poniendo ahi lo de las sessiones pero la verdad es que no entendí muy bien. ¿como podria solucionarlo?

esto me sale cuando imprimo lo que tiene $_SESSION:

CODIGO:

```
  Array
 (
 [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1522259167
 [user] => katerin.giraldo
 [domain] => CO
 [workstation] => ONWST528
 [email] => la.cast@gmail.com
 [code] => workforce
 [name] => Lalita Castrillon
  )
```

en este caso el code es workforce y yo mamejo la session asi

```
  switch ($_SESSION['code']) {
  case 'workforce':
  case 'real time analyst':
    redirect('controllers\Admin');
    break;

  case 'advocate':
    redirect('controllers\Advocate');
    break;

  case 'supervisor':
      redirect('controllers\Sup');
  break;
  case 'shift Manager':
      redirect('controllers\Manager');
  break;

  default:
    # code...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Verifica porque parece que el error no es de la base de datos sino que en la sesión no tienes una llave con el nombre **"code"**

Comment: en la sesion tengo la llave espesificada: 'code' => $code,  la llave code es igual a la variable code que traigo de la BD

Comment: Intenta hacer un print_r($_SESSION) para ke salgas de la duda

Comment: tuve que editar la pregunta para mostrarte lo que me imprime $_SESSION y si lo imprime bien, que mas podra ser?